# How is the IMPORT function with a VLOOKUP written?

Tags: google-sheets

Basically to  import the column data from a work sheet to the work sheet being worked upon?

Comment: I may upvote this brilliant question

Comment: @player0 I may upvote this question too because is edited :D, it reminds me of [this](https://youtu.be/G7RgN9ijwE4?t=4)